# how to extract column name and column value, by column number of all record from access query and / or table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create vba code to generate kml data from access data

I am just started using vba, so what I've manage to done just simple vba code to generate text file on specific path

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim Fileout As Object

'declaration to ask which table to extract
'???dim msgbox  ask for targeted table name return value as string
'^how to generate this ones???

'filepath for generated kml
'????Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(CurrentProject.Path &"\" & table name &.kml", True, True)

'kml standard header
Fileout.write "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><kml><Document><Folder>"


'?dim row number as integer
'?dim column value as string
'?dim column name as string


'loop declaration until last row
'???rowid=1
'??? columnid=4             I start at 4 because the first 3 column are reserved for coordinates and names

'???do while rowid<=last?

    'declaration of special atributes of kml(coordinates and name)
        '????Fileout.write vbNewLine & "<point><coordinates>"& column2 &","& column1 &",0</coordinates>
        '???Fileout.write vbNewLine & "<name>"& column3 &"</><description>"

    'do while columnid<=last?
        '????Fileout.write vbNewLine &"<br><b>" columnid.name &"</b>"&"" = " & columnid.value
        '???columnid = columnid+1
    '???Loop
    'rowid = rowid+1
    '???Fileout.write vbNewLine & "<description></point>"
'???Loop

'kml standard footer
Fileout.write vbNewLine & "</Document></kml>"

Fileout.Close
```

expected result are for the code to be able to use any table with any number of row and column as long as 3 defined column are placed first in this order
(not neccesary using same column name), latitude, longitude, point name.

the only successfull attemp is that  I just generate simple kml file with no success to refer column value and column name at all.

Edit:
got an idea on inputbox.. from this.. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/inputbox-function-17821927-28b7-4350-b7f1-4786575314d9
however still got no idea on geting value from the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution...
here's my final code...

```
'define input box for target table
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
Message = "Enter table/query name"  ' Set prompt.
Title = "kmlwriter"    ' Set title.
Default = "tablequeryname"    ' Set default.
MyValue = inputbox(Message, Title, Default)
'/inputbox

'define writing object for export
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'define recordset for target table fetch and looping
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [" & MyValue & "]")

'define counter and output
Dim Fileout As Object
Dim i As Integer

'set output directory, replace 'peta' with something for sub directory of your currentdatabase
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\peta\" & MyValue & ".kml", True, True)

'standard header for kml
Fileout.write "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><kml><Document><!-- Begin Style Definitions -->"


If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit

    Do Until rs.EOF = True

        'output name and coordinates, I place those 3 in order, latitude, longitude, point name
        Fileout.write vbNewLine & "<Placemark>"
        Fileout.write "<Point><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><extrude>0</extrude>"
        'rs(0) = latitude, rs(1) = longitude
        Fileout.write "<coordinates>" & rs(1) & "," & rs(0) & ",0" & "</coordinates></Point>"
        'rs(2) = point name
        Fileout.write vbNewLine & "<name>" & rs(2) & "</name><description><![CDATA["

        'output description for points
        For i = 3 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
             Fileout.write "<br><b>" & rs(i).Name & "</b> =" & rs(i)
        Next i
        Fileout.write "]]></description></Placemark>"

        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

'standard kml footer
Fileout.write vbNewLine & "</Document></kml>"

Fileout.Close

'open save directory in mazimized windows
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & CurrentProject.Path & "\peta", vbMaximizedFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Recordset()` to get your values from the tables. Basically you fetch data from your table defined by a query or a sql string, then you step from the first data row to the last data row. For example:

```
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM YourTableName", dbOpenSnapshot)

 rs.MoveFirst

 Do Until rs.EOF

   If rs.Fields("ColumnNameForID") > 3 Then         
     'Do Stuff
   End If

   rs.MoveNext

 Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```